# How to find the union of multiple lists of sub-lists

Tags: list, python-3.x

i have 6 different lists of list similar to

```
    list1=[['hello',1,2,'b3'],['world',1,2,'b4']]
    list2=[['yo',4,5,'ba'],['lolz',1,4.35,'b4']]
    list3=[['yo',4,5,'ba'],['world',3,4.35,'b6']]
    list4=[['test',4,5,'b6'],['test',4,5,'b6']]
```

they can have around 100 sub-lists in each list but they always have the 4 entries in the sub-list. I want to find all the different sub-list that are all the same and put them into a final list. so it would look something like

```
    final=[['yo',4,5,'ba'],['test',4,5,'b6']]
```

The pattern is important so the entries in the sub-lists will need to stay in order but the order of the sub-list doesn't matter. what is the best way i could do this? Thank you for your help.

Comment: Why is the `'yo'` list in the final list?  Because it appeared in more than one list?

Comment: @PatrickHaugh It is because `yo` is in the list `['yo',4,5,'ba']` which appears twice in `list2` and `list3`, similarly `['test',4,5,'b6']` appears twice in `list4`

Comment: the 'yo' sub-list is in the final list because it appeared in list2 and list3  and i tried to do a set.union of it all but it left it unorganized in it and i tried to search where it was all == but that crashed when there were multiple list of over 100 sub-lists

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that there are no unhashable elements of the sublists, I would convert them to tuples and feed them to `collections.Counter`

```
from collections import Counter

big_list = [list1, list2, ...]
c = Counter(tuple(sublist) for l in big_list for sublist in l)
final = [list(i) for i in c if c[i] > 1]
```

Comment: OP: This assumes your data is structured as `biglist = [[['hello',1,2,'b3'],['world',1,2,'b4']], [['yo',4,5,'ba'],['lolz',1,4.35,'b4']], [['test',4,5,'b6'],['test',4,5,'b6']]]`.  When you start naming variables something like `list1`, `list2`, `list3` it's a sign that you need to get rid of the names and house them in a list or another collection type.

Comment: @Patrick HaughIm im still new to python but In your code what do you mean by sublist? or how would i call a specific sublist?

Comment: @AustinTucker do you mean the `tuple(sublist)` stuff?  That's a generator expression, which you can read more about here: http://anandology.com/python-practice-book/iterators.html#generator-expressions

Comment: @AustinTucker:  `biglist` is a list of list of lists.  In the generator expression `tuple(sublist) for l in big_list for sublist in l`, `sublist` is the innermost list.  You may be confused because the generator expression contains two for-loops.  The first for-loop `for l in biglist` iterates over each item in `biglist`, which in this case are lists containing lists.  The second for-loop `for sublist in l` iterates over each item in `l`, the first of which is `['hello',1,2,'b3']`.

Comment: This doesn't seam to be working for me and i'm not sure why. Though i'm unfamiliar with what makes an unhashable element.

Comment: @AustinTucker is it throwing an exception or just not working?

Comment: The final list has more sublist in it then the original ones. Side question if one of the list, like list4 from the original example was just         list4=[], would that mess up the code you wrote?

Comment: No, that would be fine.  I'm afraid I don't quite understand what you mean.  Are you saying that the list `final` has more sublists than all of the lists in `big_list`?  Maybe you could post your inputs and outputs as an edit to your question.

Comment: I got it now. the error i think was because i had some list equal to each other to fix an error i was getting in another part of the code but i bypasses that and your code worked. Thank you